# Folder metada - transfer automatically on File

Tags: document-library, folder, metadata

I have a document library that contains folders. In those folders, I have some files. I would like to transfer the metadata from the folder to the files in it. Does anyone know how I can do it?

Thank you,
Lidia

Comment: It is better to use [Document Sets](https://support.microsoft.com/office/introduction-to-document-sets-3dbcd93e-0bed-46b7-b1ba-b31de2bcd234?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) in such scenarios. If you are still in development phase or if there are few folders/files, you can consider using documents sets. Else, you will have to use Power automate or PowerShell to update file metadata based on metadata of parent folder.